# Python text based game

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write code in Python for a text based game for my class and am having several issues. First, for some reason, the code isn't even running now when I try to debug it. When it was working, every time I'd enter a command, it would always print multiple lines of 'Enter a valid move', whether or not the command was valid. I am also having trouble on how to collect the item from each room and add it to the inventory.

```
rooms = {
        'Living Room': {'north': "Parent's Room", 'east': "Kitchen",'south': 'Dining Room', 'west' : 'Office'},
        "Parent's Room": {'east': "Amir's Room", 'south' : 'Living Room', 'item' : 'cape'},
        "Amir's Room": {'west': "Parent's Room"},
        'Office': {'east': 'Living Room', 'item' : 'Toy Phone'}, 
        'Dining Room': {'north': 'Living Room', 'east': 'Garage', 'item': 'Toy Taco'},
        'Garage' : {'west': 'Dining Room', 'item': 'Toy Car'},
        'Kitchen' : {'west': 'Living Room', 'north' : 'Pantry', 'item' : 'Toy Fork'},
        'Pantry' : {'south' : 'Kitchen', 'item' : 'Chocolate'}
    }
direction = '' # Creates empty variable for direction.
location = 'Living Room' # Places user in default starting point
inventory = []

def show_status(): 
    ''' Shows player status and commands.'''

def main():
    # Keep game going until player enters 'exit'
    while True:
        print('----------------------------')
        print('You are in the {}.'.format(location))
        
        input = input('Enter a direction to move: ').strip().lower() # Take input from user to move them in desired direction.
        direction = input.split()

        # Check to see if user entered valid move.
        for command in rooms[location]:
            if direction == command:
                location = rooms[location][direction]
                print(direction)
            elif direction != command: 
                print('Enter a valid move')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn’t running because the `main()` function is never called.

Add this to the very end of your Python file:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Other than that… your code, as is, has countless runtime bugs that make it impossible for the code to work as you intended it to. Just as an example, here are a few problems with your code that need to be fixed before you can do anything else:

1. Add the previously mentioned code to call `main()`
2. Make `location` accessible via the `main()` function, for example by adding `global location` as the first line of your `main()`.
3. Rename your `input` variable because you cannot reassign the built-in function called `input()`. Rename it to `input_str`, for example.
4. Fix the logic inside of the very last `if… else` block: the `elif` block shouldn’t print `“Enter a valid move”` after every single iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are many problems with your program, let's go quickly throught them.

First, to run this program you need to call main function somewhere or use

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # rest of your program
```

Second problem is the input function reads from stdin but here:

```
input = (
    input("Enter a direction to move: ").strip().lower()
)  # Take input from user to move them in desired direction.
```

You override it! You need to rename your variable to e.g. **user_input**

Next problem is

```
if direction == command:
```

If you think the condition should be satisfied but isn't and you are more advanced, try to learn how to use debugger. If not the `print` statement will be enough for start

```
print(command) # prints 'north'
print(direction) # prints ['north']
```

So we discovered another problem - indeed

```
direction = my_input.split()
```

split() creates list so you try to compare list to string which won't work in that case.

And to travel around all rooms you can loop over dict:

```
for room_name, subdict in rooms.items(): #here subdict is a dictionary
    for command, subroom in subdict.items():
        (do what you need)
```

Comment: Dang, you were a lot more patient than I was haha. The code was so bad that I didn’t feel like re-writing their entire script for them. EDIT: you missed one runtime exception; the `location` variable is out of scope.

Comment: @KyleNakamura you know, it's sleep time, the time when we treat everything as more interesting than sleep :D
Indeed the code has some... inadequacies but hope the op will be able to progress further with our hints